# Java8 : How to filter a map of List value via stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm still a beginner of Java 8. I'm getting stuck on filtering a Map of List values. Here is my code

```
public class MapFilterList {
    private static Map<String, List<Person>> personMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person("John", 22);
        Person p2 = new Person("Smith", 45);
        Person p3 = new Person("Sarah", 27);

        List<Person> group1 = new ArrayList<>();
        group1.add(p1);
        group1.add(p2);

        List<Person> group2 = new ArrayList<>();
        group2.add(p2);
        group2.add(p3);

        List<Person> group3 = new ArrayList<>();
        group3.add(p3);
        group3.add(p1);

        personMap.put("group1", group1);
        personMap.put("group2", group2);
        personMap.put("group3", group3);

        doFilter("group1").forEach(person -> {
            System.out.println(person.getName() + " -- " + person.getAge());
        });

    }

    public static List<Person> doFilter(String groupName) {
        return personMap.entrySet().stream().filter(key -> key.equals(groupName)).map(map -> map.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

How can I make to correct `doFilter` method because the error show me `cannot convert from List<List<Person>> to List<Person>`.

Comment: What you want to achieve? Why not just `personMap.get(groupName)`? As I understand, `doFilter` should do exactly this job.

Comment: @Zefick I was praticing Java8 lambda expression and Stream API. This program is just an example. I'd like to filter a map of list values via it's stream.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct the doFilter method"? Is something not working? Is there an error? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @yyannekk The error show me *Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<Person>> to List<Person>*

Comment: Even when you are practicing Java 8, you should try to solve tasks that exhibit a benefit of the Stream API over the older APIs, instead of tasks that are simpler without Streams. The entire operation can be expressed as either `personMap.get(groupName)` or, if collecting into a new list really is required, still as simple as `new ArrayList<>(personMap.get(groupName))`…

Comment: @Holger yeah ... I just tried to simplify the question and I know exactly where is the point that I don't know how to figure. As the OP **How to filter a map of List value via stream** , I would like to filter a map by it's stream. The problem wasn't **how to get a value from map**.

Comment: But possible solutions depend on the actual problem. Even if you weren’t looking for an exact match of the key (which is what `get` is for), using a predicate that is known to have exactly one match implies that you could use `findFirst` or similar to get the particular `List`. Collecting into a new list is only necessary, if you know that you will have to merge multiple lists into one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understood correctly you need the following code:

```
public static List<Person> doFilter(String groupName) {
    return personMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(groupName))
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            // as an option to replace the previous two
            // .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my error. can you explain me why you use `flatMap`  method ?

Comment: `flatMap` converts `Stream<List<Person>>` to `Stream<Person>`

Comment: You can fuse `.map(entry -> entry.getValue()) .flatMap(List::stream)` to a single `.flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())`

Comment: @Holger Thank you for more shorter way.